# How to SELECT timestamp for every 5 minutes from date in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql, t-sql, timestamp, where-clause

I'm using MS SQL Server and I need SELECT that return only data like:

```
SELECT TOP 100000 [timestamp], [value] as fi500
FROM X
where timestamp>='2019-11-05' + 5 minute
order by timestamp
```

So I got:

[image: I got:]

But I need like :

[image]

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: What is your logic for this? Why would a value for 00:00:30 be displayed at 00:05:00 and for 00:00:40 at 00:10:00, etc? That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Please don't look data at 'fi500' - it is a example from excel. It is coincidence that value for 00:00:30 is the same for 00:05:00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks like SQL Server.  You can check that the `timestamp` meets your conditions using `datetimefromparts()` and

```
select top (100000) [timestamp], [value] as fi500
from X
where timestamp = datetimefromparts(2019, 11, 05,
                                    datepart(hour, timestamp),
                                    (datepart(minute, timestamp) / 5) * 5,
                                    0, 0
                                   )
order by timestamp;
```

Comment: @bobialen, could you accept the answer which helps you more? I notice that you have not accept any answer yet in your four questions?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use MOD in WHERE clause.

If timestamp is stored as seconds it could be

`... WHERE MOD(timestamp, 300) = 0 ...`

to check if seconds number is divisible by 60*5.